# Glib: g_ascii_dtostr imprecise?

Tags: c, string, double, glib, double-precision

I am a little bit intrigued by the way some glib functions such as "g_ascii_dtostr" (and the GKeyFile functions using doubles) work.

Consider this line:

```
gchar buf[30];
g_message("Double: %f, as String: %s", 0.2, g_ascii_dtostr(buf, 30, 0.2));
```

Which outputs

```
Double: 0.200000, as String: 0.20000000000000001
```

(The weird conversion only happens when I set the buffer size high enough though)

Similar things happen when I (for example) store the double "1.9" in a GKeyFile, but in the resulting file it is saved as "1.8999999999999999".
Apparently the conversion back through "g_ascii_strtod" is supposed to be lossless, but it still bothers me why this weirdness happens in the first place. Also this makes my config key-value files pretty ugly..

I think I have read somewhere once that an intermediate "long double" type is used, but this still wouldn't clarify why the converted value is "dirty", because e.g. a conversion from int to double for doesn't have any similar effects I think.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: A pointer to the most frequent floating-point-related answer on stackoverflow (or anywhere else?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6033242/12711

Comment: @Mysticial Thank you, I will read that paper later, but for now, basically, when I store the value "1.9" it could never have been stored precisely in the first place because in binary, it has infinite digits. Is that correct?

Comment: If you change the `%f` to `%.18f` you'll see a similar output from the `0.2` literal too.

Comment: http://player.vimeo.com/video/7516539#t=7m26s is short and fun.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-dtostr):

"This functions generates enough precision that converting the string back using g_ascii_strtod() gives the same machine-number (on machines with IEEE compatible 64bit doubles)."

As caf noted in his comment, the %f specifier truncates after six decimal digits, so g_ascii_strtod() gives you the more accurate value. You can use g_ascii_formatd() if you want this truncation.