# Set precision inside a function

Tags: r, precision

I am trying to figure out how to increase precision of an output of a function. I need to have output of `acf` function with at least 5 digits accuracy, while it gives me 3.

```
v = c(1.1,3.2,2.1,4.5) 
acfv = acf(v) 
acfv
```

The only precision-adjusting function I know is `options(digits=...)`, which works only for explicit calculations in global environment. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Reproducible example please

Comment: v = c(1.1,3.2,2.1,4.5) 

    acfv = acf(v) 

    acfv

Comment: So acf returns output with 2-digits precision and I need higher precision (e.g. 5).

Comment: You are mixing number of shown digits from printing results with precision of values (computer arithmetic). That are two different things. http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033184/how-computer-does-floating-point-arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just looking at the print-method output. The acf values are stored in full numeric precision:

```
> acfv$acf
, , 1

           [,1]
[1,]  1.0000000
[2,] -0.3399337
[3,]  0.2900897
[4,] -0.4501561
```